# Отправка/прием клиентом UDP датаграмм через Http прокси

Tags: c#, udp, proxy

Есть **клиент**, хочет отправить **datagram** на **сервер**, но он за **прокси**, вот беда.

Есть конечно прокси с Socks4,5 (но, насколько я знаю, это частные случаи) интересует соединение именно через http прокси.

**UPD:** В случае же Tcp все довольно просто:
при соединении к прокси в запросе указываем CONNECT > Host: ...  и работаем уже с прокси > GET > Host: ...,

Но как установить соединение с сервером работающим по UDP?

Comment: @michael, уточните. 

Вас интересует, как самому написать такую прокси (А какой сервер ?) ?  

Или как настроить нечто конкретное, но не озвученное Вами ?

Comment: Нет, необходимо установить соединение с сервером через проксю.

Comment: Что значит "установить соединение" в случае UDP?

Comment: Реализовать возможность отправки получения данных.

Comment: Так прокси уже есть? Какой? Если он такого не позволяет, то что будете делать? Если есть возможность переставить, то (я уже не помню socks4-socks5) может быть их? Или какой-нибудь маршрутизатор c NAT/ip maskerading?

Comment: Интересует общий случай. Приложение может находится за любым из известных прокси. Интересует процесс создания туннеля. Например сейчас я пытаюсь достучатся через squid, socks4,socks5 по дефолту выключен.

Comment: Почитайте [RFC1928](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1928.html), м.б. найдете что-то полезное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но как установить соединение с сервером работающим по UDP?

Невозможно. В принципе. Можно открыть порт и ждать входящих пакетов. Можно отправить пакет, он уйдёт и получатель может быть его получит. Не более того.

> Есть клиент, хочет отправить datagram на сервер, но он за прокси, вот беда.

Невозможно. http-proxy работает по протоколу TCP. Он слушает TCP порт (3128, 8080  и т.д.). Просто протокол HTTP в принципе работает через TCP (за исключением некоторых случаев) и ничего с этим не сделаешь.

Comment: Про установить соединение это я в курсе: имелось ввиду отсылка пакета через прокси. А за второе спасибо, но разве нельзя попросить прокси открыть udp туннель?

Comment: Ведь даже те же он-лайн игрушки используют для связи с сервером - udp, и прокси им не помеха.

Comment: Помеха. Они либо работают через NAT а не прокси, либо переключаются на tcp, либо используют не http, а socks5 прокси.